# Odd behaviour with RelativeLayout using layout_alignParentBottom

Tags: android, layout, view, android-relativelayout

I have come across a weird behaviour in Relative Layout today and can't understand why this is happening:

1) Here is the Layout with layout_alignParentBottom in the first inner edit text to true (Notice how yellow view should not expand all the height):

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/chat_layout"
                tools:context=".MainActivity"
                android:background="#FF0000">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomlayout"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFF000">
        <EditText
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:id="@+id/chat_edit_text2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:text="edit text">

        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/chat_edit_text1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_above="@id/chat_edit_text2"
            android:text="text above">

        </EditText>


    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The result is this:

[image]

Now if we remove the layout_alignParentBottom="true" in the inner edit text the layout is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/chat_layout"
                tools:context=".MainActivity"
                android:background="#FF0000">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomlayout"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFF000">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/chat_edit_text2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:text="edit text">

        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/chat_edit_text1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_above="@id/chat_edit_text2"
            android:text="text above">

        </EditText>


    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the Result:

[image]

What I was expecting:

1) In the first case I expect both editboxes to appear stacked one over the other (This is correct in the result) but the Inner relative layout should not become full height. It should occupy just the space both edit boxes take because the relative layout has a wrap_content

2) In the second case I expect both editboxes to appear stacked and they don't. But the size the inner relative layout takes is correct (taking into account editboxes are not being correctly stacked one over the other)

I'm using last android studio stable version with sdk 23.

What is happening here?

Comment: It is kind of hard to explain but I will try. With wrap_content height on the RelativeLayout containing the EditText you are saying I want the height to wrap the content. You are then saying you want the content to be aligned to the bottom of the parent. Well, the parent can stretch to match the height of it's parent while still wrapping its content. So the call to alignParentBottom on the EditText is stretching the container to the height of it's parent. If you don't have the attribute set on the EditText, the RelativeLayout will wrap it's content, and then align to it's parent's bottom.

Comment: Well, I understood what you you meant. Anyway all that matters is how android iterprets this because I think there are different valid interpretations. I will just accept this works this way :). On the other hand, why does second example do not stack both edit boxes correctly?